# How to apply Excel settings only to a range using Epplus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, export-to-excel, epplus, epplus-4

For the values `i=4 and i=6`, following will apply background color as `LightGrey` to the `entire` 4th and 6th rows. **Question**: Are there any ways so we change the Background color (or any style for that matter) of a row within certain range, say, all the rows from 1st column to the 10th column?

```
int i;
ExcelRow rowRange = ws.Row(i);
ExcelFill RowFill = rowRange.Style.Fill;
RowFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
```

Comment: Well you need to start with getting a reference to a range that only points to the cells you want. Doing `ws.Row(i)` isn't going to get you that, because that will be the entire row.

Comment: @mason I tried with `ExcelRange ExlRange = ws.Cells[1, 1, 50, 10];` (covering first 50 rows and 10 columns) but `ExcelRange` does not seem to have `ExcelRow` or `ExcelColumn` so the above code did not work for `ExlRange`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ws.Row(rowNumber)` use

```
var firstColumn =  1;
var lastColumn  = 10;
var rowRange    = ws.Cells[rowNumber, firstColumn, rowNumber, lastColumn];
//now do styling on rowRange
```

`rowRange` will contain references to all the cells in the rectangle defined by the values you passed to it.

Comment: Line `ExcelFill rowFill     = ws.Cells[........]` gives the error `cannot implicitly convert ExcelRange to ExcelFill`. I can't use `var` since we need to have `RowFill.PatternType` property set first in order to use `RowFill.BackgroundColor`

Comment: Look at my edited answer. I was using different variable names than you were.